# Nothing happens when macro is executed

Tags: vba, excel

I have a locked excel  sheet, and I want that when the sheet is getting activated by the user,  unlockthe range of cells that accomplish a condition (i.e. if cell A1 is > 0 then unlock Range A2:A5).

On the other hand, I also want unlock always the Range K1:K372.

I already have this code:

```
    ' macro activates by activating the Worksheet       
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
' macro activates by activating the Worksheet
' Set a counter to iterate through all the rows where to if the cell accomplishes the condition
Dim rowtolock As Integer
rowtolock = 5


Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
'select the first cell where I will check if the value is greater or less than 0
   Range("M" & rowtolock).Select
    ' if the seleted cell value is greater or equal than 0, unprotect the sheet (because it´s protectet), select the range I want to unlock so that the user can makes changes JUST on those cells, unlock them, and finally lock anotherway the sheet.
   If ActiveCell.Value >= 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
        Range("B" & rowtolock & ":G" & rowtolock).Select
        Selection.Locked = False
        Selection.FormulaHidden = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    End If
    ' add 1 to the counter, so that the next selected cell is one row below
    rowtolock = rowtolock + 1
Loop

'unprotect sheet, unlock range, and protect sheet
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
Range("K1:K372").Select
Selection.Locked = False
Selection.FormulaHidden = False
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End Sub
```

This code actually works on my computer at home, but on my computer at work, it executes the macro, but nothing changes, all the cells/ the whole sheet is locked, but not the range K1:K372

Somebody knows what is happening or what could be different at home than at work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should debug it on your work computer to see where it fails (if starts at all). As it runs well in one pc probably the code is right.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correct, you need to make a selection on the active sheet and if the condition satisfies, you need to do something. Right? But Is your Do Until Loop is correct?

`ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
 Range("B" & rowtolock & ":G" & rowtolock).Select
 Selection.Locked = False`

When you call like this ( Range("B" & rowtolock & ":G" & rowtolock).Select), I hope the active cell changes in the sheet. Then the next iteration will check for the code selected cell.NOT THE ONE YOU ARE SELECTED (May be your home work sheet satisfied the condition: Just a Guess!)

Best thing is to debug your loop and check the ActiveCell value. Thanks !!!

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I debugged it, and I saw that the macro wasn't executing the do until loop, so I selected before the cell, and then it worked. Don´t know if it's logical, but I' glad that it works.

Comment: You are always well come. I made the answer by debugging as well :) The the loop was not executing with the selection. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks! :)